# C# read text file with HEX value and show it as byte []?

Tags: c#, file, io, byte

I want to take a text file that only have hex value
this is the text file :

```
0xD2 0x00 0xD3 0x04 0xD4 0x77 0x21 0x21 0x3F 0x21 0x21 0x20 0x21 0x23 0x20 0x21 0x3F 0x20 0x21 0x23 0x20 0x21 0x21 0x3F 0x21 0x21
```

and save it as a byte[] array

so the byte array will be :
byte[] file ={0xD1, 0X00, ........ ,0x21 ,0x21}
can I do this ?

- if needed I can change the file  - remove the spaces, the 0x ...

Thanks ,

Comment: If you remove the spaces and the 0x, the task becomes easier (read pairs of chars and do simple math with them)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var numbersAsString = "0xD2 0x00 0xD3"; // shortend your example a bit
var numbersAsInts = numbersAsString.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbersAsInts.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()))
```

Comment: Does `Convert.ToByte(...)` handle 0x?

Comment: @someone: [Like a charm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_) 

But it is also possible to provide an `IFormatProvider`

Comment: where do I read the file here , and what the text in the fiole should be?

Comment: You may use something like `File.ReadAllText` for that.

Comment: not good - because when I read the file this is what I get ; A2 which should be 162(decimal) , but in File.ReadAllText and then byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input); I get 65 50 . how to fix this ?

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. No one here told you to use this. It convertes your chars to its ASCII value. A has the code 65 and 2 has the value 50. 
You do `var numbersAsString = File.ReadAllText('filename.txt')`.

Comment: so what I need to write ? - I don't understand . Thanks